# Given pair of graph is isomorphic?

Tags: graph-isomorphism

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyt67.jpg)I am stuck on this graph. Not sure how to map this I have research everywhere but can't find satisfying answer. I am asking this question on someone's behalf I do not know how to ask this question properly or what i formation is missing but I do my best to give all information i have. Below is the picture

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have uploaded the picture @Gonçalo

Comment: The first graph is known as "Petersen graph".

Answer (score 1):

The graphs are isomorphic. Rename the vertices of the second graph as
\begin{align}
V_1&\to W_1 \\
V_2&\to W_2 \\
V_3&\to W_3 \\
V_4&\to W_8 \\
V_5&\to W_6 \\
V_6&\to W_5 \\
V_7&\to W_4 \\
V_8&\to W_9 \\
V_9&\to W_{10} \\
V_{10}&\to W_7
\end{align}
Now you can check that for each edge $(U_i,U_j)$ of the first graph corresponds the edge $(W_i,W_j)$ of the second graph, and vice-versa.